# Memory when importing js objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and its transpiled way of generating javascript.

In react side, I have a class `Utility` that uses a data object `UserData` organized as below -

UserDataObj.js

```
class UserData{
  this.someobj = {};
  //some function here
  something(){

  }
}

const UserDataObj = new UserData();
export {UserDataObj};
```

Utility.js

```
import {UserDataObj} from './data/UserDataObj';
class Utility {
    doSomething(){
      //UserDataObj.something();
    }
}
const utility = new Utility();
export {utility};
```

I have another ReactApp UserApp.js, that also uses UserDataObj and Utility (although not good design wise) -

```
import {UserDataObj} from './data/UserDataObj';
import {utility} from './Utility';
class UserApp extends React.Component{
    //does something with UserDataObj
    // also does somethign with utility
}
```

My question is, how many `utility` and `UserDataObj` instances will be created in memory, when `UserApp` is rendered. My guess is, it should be only 1 instance for both. But I want to confirm if importing `n` times creates a new instance every time.

Any good read on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the bundling tool, and not React. I imagine that the new browser ES Module resolution scheme works in the same way.

Most bundlers that I know of, and other import schemes such as Node.js' `require` module resolution will cache the import between files and always return the same exported objetcs. This is a requirement for prototype inheritance, for example, otherwise, it would mess up the `instanceof` operator.

That exported `new Utility()` instance will be the same for any module that imports it. In order to generate new instances, you would have to have a function.

Comment: Just to clarify, any other script running in the *same execution environment* will share the same imported object. This will not work across browser pages, different machines, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Marcus.